# Extracting a phrase from a line c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, parsing

There is a line in which data references are stored. How can I parse it to get only a specific link? 
Example line:

```
string urls = "<a href='DocumentEditor.aspx?IdDocument=874551' target='_blank'>Договор аренды №  09/03-12 от  16.03.2012, с  16.03.2012 по  15.03.2017 ;</a><br>Арендатор: <a href='ContragentEditor.aspx?IdContragent=43938' target='_blank'>  Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "Строй-Союз"(*) </a></br><br>;<a href='DocumentEditor.aspx?IdDocument=1064925' target='_blank'>Договор аренды № 01/01-16 от 15.07.2011, с 25.11.2011 по 26.01.2021;</a><br>Арендатор: <a href='ContragentEditor.aspx?IdContragent=58283' target='_blank'>  ООО "Строительно-транспортная компания "ЭкоСтрой" </a></br><br>"
```

I need to get from this line:

```
string getRow = "a href='DocumentEditor.aspx?IdDocument=1064925' target='_blank'>Договор аренды № 01/01-16 от 15.07.2011, с 25.11.2011 по 26.01.2021;</a><br>Арендатор: <a href='ContragentEditor.aspx?IdContragent=58283' target='_blank'>  ООО "Строительно-транспортная компания "ЭкоСтрой" </a></br><br>""
```

There can be any number of links in the line. How can I extract from this line a specific link, for example 1 or the last ?

Comment: Use a proper html parser. The first that comes to mind is HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good reference on how to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a split on ' and check if one of the parts contains .aspx. But this technique is far from perfect.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string[] getRowArr = Regex.Split(getRow, "'");
foreach (string item in getRowArr)
{
    if (item.ToLower().Contains(".aspx") || item.ToLower().Contains(".com"))
    {
        Label1.Text += item + "<br />";
    }
}
```

But how your string are now they won't even compile! This does not work: `я "ЭкоСтрой" </a></br><br>""`